# System.Linq.Dynamic - ParseException: syntax error

Tags: c#, expression, dynamic-linq

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var expressionString = "Property == \"MySt\\\"ring\"";
        var p = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test));
        var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expressionString);
    }
}
```

On executing this, an exception of type `ParseException` is thrown. The requirement is to have a string literal with a quote in between.

**Edit:** I have also tried removing \\ from `MyString` with no change in exception.

Can somebody please share some ideas?

Comment: What is you expressionstring? Is it `Property == "MySt ring"`?

Comment: @PawanS, It's `Property == "MySt"ring"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can write:

```
"Property == \"MySt\"\"ring\""
```

Here's the tokenization code from System.Linq.Dynamic source code:

```
case '"':
case '\'':
    char quote = ch;
    do {
        NextChar();
        while (textPos < textLen && ch != quote) NextChar();
        if (textPos == textLen)
            throw ParseError(textPos, Res.UnterminatedStringLiteral);
        NextChar();
    } while (ch == quote);
    t = TokenId.StringLiteral;
    break;
```

Comment: First one (`"Property == \"MySt\"\"ring\""`) works while second one failed with message `Character literal must contain exactly one character`

Comment: Ok so in dynamic linq simple quotes are for character literals, just like in C#.

Comment: Is there any C# method which would simply duplicate and escaped character as in the answer?

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `yourstring.Replace("\"", "\"\"")` ?

Comment: Considering all other escape sequences?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to dynamically build a query string. The other escapes are here because it's a C# string. The real query that is passed to the lib is just `Property == "MySt""ring"`. But you should use parameters. I don't have the doc right now so I can't tell you the exact syntax, but I recall you can parameterize your queries.